# Read a csv file and for each record read, insert into another file

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a windows form application. I want to know how I can read one line and then insert it into another file and then continue to the next line and so on.

For now, I am loading the file on a grdiview. Here is an image:

[image]

The process would be:

a) read line 1 -> insert that line into another file

b) read line 2 -> insert that line into another file

My code is here:

```
private void BindDataCsv(string FilePath)
    {
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);

        if (Lines.Length > 0)
        {
            string FirstLine = Lines[0];

            string[] HeaderLabels = FirstLine.Split(';');

            foreach (string HeaderWord in HeaderLabels)
            {
                Dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(HeaderWord));
            }

            for (int r = 1; r < Lines.Length; r++)
            {
                string[] DataWords = Lines[r].Split(';');

                DataRow Dr = Dt.NewRow();

                int ColumnIndex = 0;

                foreach (string HeaderWord in HeaderLabels)
                {
                    Dr[HeaderWord] = DataWords[ColumnIndex++];
                }

                Dt.Rows.Add(Dr);
            }
        }

        if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dgvData.DataSource = Dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like an incredibly slow and labor intensive way of performing a `File.Copy` - could you go into detail as to why you aren't just copying the file? Do the contents of the file need to be shown in the datagridview also, or are you just using it for some temporary storage?

Comment: Because he wants each line in the CSV to go into its own file.

Comment: I want to know how I can do that because I somecase, I could also read the file line by line and then insert into database... Or read line by line and with each line consume a web service. The datagridview is temporary.

Comment: Is this not what the code you have posted already does? Reads line by line, and then inserts into a datarow in a datatable.. You're already demonstrating a line by line operation with this?

Comment: No I only load the csv file into the datagrid view, but I wanto to know how when I read a line, then that line insert into another file. I don't want to load all the file and then create another file

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll admit I don't really understand what you're trying to do or why the posted code doesn't already demonstrate to you what you're asking (it does everything but write to a file, which isn't much more complicated than writing a datarow into a datatable), but here's a simple app that reads a file line by line and writes those lines, line by line, to another (single) file:

```
using(StreamWriter output = File.AppendText(@"C:\temp\output.txt")){
  foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\input.txt"))
    output.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Here's code that reads from one file and creates N new files, one line per file. A 1000 line file becomes 1000 one line files:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\input.txt"))
  File.WriteAllText($"C:\\temp\\output{i++}.txt", line);
```

Here's some code that reads a file line by line and calls a web service. It is assumed the web service is [already set up according to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2019)

```
SomeWebServiceClient wsc = new SomeWebServiceClient();
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\input.txt"))
  wsc.RemoteMethodThatTakesASingleStringParameter(line);
```

Comment: If I want to load the file and then with each line consume a web service... how it can be done?

Comment: In my interpretation "consuming" a webservice is making a design time decision of which webservice you want to attach to, pointing VS at it by creating a service reference and letting it create a bunch of stub classes and a client so that you can call web service operations; it's not something I regard one would do in a runtime context by reading a file and carrying out a consumption per line of the file. What does "consuming" a webservice mean to you?

Comment: Use the ws methods. So for example, my ws insert data into database... So I load a csv file and then I go line by line consuming the insert method. So I don't wait to load all the file, I go line by line so I can stop the process when I want

Comment: [File.ReadLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8) starts an iterator that gradually reads the file. It is different to ReadALlLines, which reads the whole file into an array in memory. To send the data to the web service, first add it as a service reference and then call the appropriate client method. I'l ladd an example

Comment: In my code, after I add row how i can do something with that line added?

Comment: These questions are getting harder to answer because they're both getting broader, and making less sense. *"By writing another line of code after `Dt.Rows.Add(Dr)` that does something with the line"*. If by "do something" you mean manipulate the string, then you can't - not only because strings are immutable and cannot be changed once created, but also because iteration variables cannot be reassigned to something else (a rule of the language)